# Sending a message through an Azure Service Bus Queue and use it in an Logic Apps not working (failed to load content)

Tags: azure, message-queue, azure-logic-apps

I'm using an Azure Service Bus in the format text/plain. Then I use a LogicApp and want to receive those message and store the content in a varibale.

```
When the LogicApp is trying to open the content, I get an error message:
Failed to fetch: 
'{"url":"https://{url}.azurewebsites.net:443/runtime/webhooks/workflow/scaleUnits/prod- 
00/workflows/9da55c451e224a589492f615bee4487d/runs/08585170986495026723822843804CU00/contents/TriggerInputs?api-version=2018-11-01&code=9OHQZOR8zU5FyKHcszRVXFiG1jm2RALYar8QvZQgT-yiAzFuAlVxmQ%3d%3d&se=2023-05-19T19%3A00%3A00.0000000Z&sp=%2Fruns%2F08585170986495026723822843804CU00%2Fcontents%2FTriggerInputs%2Fread&sv=1.0&sig=EALoc5FWMhfEVWpv9ahLU7vMjoV0a64WOtRf2KBW7IA","exception":{}}'.
```

[image: error in Logic Apps screenshot]

[image: error in Logic Apps Screenshot]

and see the Screeshots. I don't know where to start to debug the error.

Best regards

Matthias

Answer (score 0):

After reproducing from my end, I faced the same issue due to Access restrictions.

[image]

When I disabled the access restriction and allowed public access this was working fine.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where did you find the access restriction menu? I can't find it.

Comment: You need to navigate to Networking from side pane and under Inbound Traffic you can find access restriction https://i.imgur.com/6dzReat.png